# What are the “protocols” to the ECHR?

Tags: european-union, human-rights, european-court-of-human-rights

The European convention of human rights has “protocols” to it. What essentially are these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [protocols](https://treaties.un.org/Pages/overview.aspx?path=overview/definition/page1_en.xml#protocols) are listed and linked in this [pdf](https://echr.coe.int/Documents/Library_Collection_ProtocolsTable_ENG.pdf). It also explains:

> Over the last 50 years additional protocols have been repealed, integrated into the Convention or replaced, and today, the text of the ECHR contains the basic version as amended by Protocol 11 and 14, and 8 other protocols: the Additional Protocol (also called "Protocol No. 1") and Protocols Nos. 4, 6, 7,12, 13, 15 and 16.

No protocol is the same. To understand what one is and its relationship to a related treaty, you need to read it. For example [Protocol 1](https://www.echr.coe.int/Documents/Library_Collection_P1postP11_ETS009E_ENG.pdf) directly says:

> As between the High Contracting Parties the provisions of Articles 1, 2, 3 and 4 of this Protocol shall be
> regarded as additional articles to the Convention and all the provisions of the Convention shall apply
> accordingly.

Comment: But what *ARE* “protocols”?

Comment: Why are they called protocols though?

Comment: @Seekinganswers That’s just a common term for new agreements added to a treaty regime.